# Are OPCODEs for ETH and ETC different?

Tags: ethereum-classic, opcode

I deployed an exactly same contract to both ETH and ETC.
And I could see the contract doesn't work correctly only on ETC.

```
contract ContractA {
    ContractB public BB;

    // Common
    constructor () public {
        BB = ContractB(msg.sender);
    }

    function () public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0);

        BB.destination().transfer(msg.value);
        BB.logDeposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
}
```

It seems that it fails on the line `BB.destination().transfer(msg.value);`. I think reading `destination()` works and then it fails when it tries transferring.

I suspect that the OPCODEs for those chains are different, but couldn't get any clue.

Comment: afaik ETC took a different branch for their EVM , they have their own EIPs.  but intersting question indeed

Comment: Is it possible that the VM implementation of Ethereum Classic is not up-to-date with the last changes? (e.g., the opcode REVERT is present in the go ethereum implementation https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/opcodes.go), while it is not present in the go-ethereum classic impelementation https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/opcodes.go..

Answer (score 2):

At the moment ETC does not have certain new opcodes that solidity assumes exist. To compile contracts for ETC you need to use Solidity version <=0.4.19.

Come January/February 2019 we should expect that ETC will upgrade and become opcode compatible with current versions of Solidity. Longer term there are other solutions that will be implemented.